# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar la impresión de los paths en el terminal?

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código, que me muestra la impresión de `paths` de algunos archivos guardados en una variable. En la terminal, el código me imprime los paths. Pero estos archivos están ordenados por fecha.
¿Por que en me imprime los archivos de forma desordenada?

¿Alguna idea?

Mi código es:

```
path = 'PLO-2007'
total = 0

files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if ".fits" in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r,file))
            total +=1

for f in files: 
    print("\\"+f)

print(total)
```

Comment: por favor indica qué te sale, qué falla y qué querrías que saliera.

Comment: Me imprime en el terminal todos los paths de los archivos guardados en una variable. como digo de forma desordenada, no se que puedo agregar al código para que sea de forma ordenada

Comment: dale a [edit] para incluir estos datos. Revisa [ask] para más detalles de cómo formular preguntas chachis

Comment: ¿Y cual es el orden que esperas?

Comment: Son archivos en formato fits, estan ordenados por fecha, me sale cualquier fecha

Comment: Lo que quieres es ordenarlos por fecha ?

Comment: Si, creo que algo debería añadir al código.

Comment: Por qué dices que están ordenados por fecha? La fecha está en el nombre del archivo?

Comment: @Alfabravo, exacto.

Comment: Entonces, por favor añade a tu pregunta (editándola) un ejemplo de nombre de archivo, pues con tu código sólo se ve que validas que contenga `.fits` y no sabemos dónde quieres buscar la fecha

Comment: `os.walk()` retorna la lista con un orden arbitrario, como por defecto te retorna los archivos un `dir` común de DOS/Windows. Si quieres un orden, tienes que generar previamente la lista con los datos apropiados y ordenarla ad-hoc. ¿Ordenar por nombre de archivo te alcanzaría?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, Si quiero que me ordene por nombre de archivo.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, me puedes dar una idea.

Comment: Antes de iterar con `f` prueba ordenar la lista con `f.sort()`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho, lo coloco antes del for pero no me ordena nada.

Comment: Ordenar lo debe estar haciendo, pero seguramente no de la forma en que lo estas esperando. Agrega a tu pregunta algunos ejemplos de nombres de archivo como para entender el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes ordenar tu lista de archivos antes de mostrarla por fecha de modificación o de creación según lo necesites. para hacerlo yo crearia una lista de objectos donde tendré la fecha de modificacion y el nombre del archivo para ordernar mis objetos por la fecha de modificación o el valor que necesite dentro de él. quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
import os
from operator import itemgetter
path = 'PLO-2007'
total = 0
files = []
my_paths = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    if r not in my_paths:
        my_paths.append(r)
    for file in f:
        if ".fits" in file:
            tfile=os.path.join(r,file)
            #Obtengo la fecha de modificación del archivo
            #Puedo usar getctime para obtener la fecha de creación
            files.append({"modified_date": os.path.getmtime(tfile), "file": tfile})
            total +=1
#Ordeno mi lista de archivos usando el key "modified_date" del objeto.
files=sorted(files, key=itemgetter("modified_date"))

for f in files: 
    print(f)

for i in range(len(my_paths)): 
    print(i, my_paths[i])

print(total)
```

Espero te sea util, saludos.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿hay un límite con respecto a los archivos que se deben imprimir en la pantalla?, lo corroboró con la carpeta y no todos me salen.

Comment: No, valída que todos tengan la extensión .fits.

Comment: ¿Entonces el problema estaría en los archivos? Por que no todos me aparecen tengo carpetas con 236 y 338 archivos y especialmente los primeros no me salen

Comment: En el `for file in f:` coloca un `print(r,file)` para que veas todos tus archivos sin importar la extensión y manualmente valida que existan con la extensión correcta.

Comment: No salen todos los archivos, me deja un errado no sera la carpeta

Comment: ¿No sera un exceso de archivos?

Comment: Los archivos me salen salteados y algunos no los detecta

Comment: Acabo de hacer una prueba con 1269 archivos sin problemas. que OS manejas?

Comment: Yo trabajo con Linux Ubuntu

Comment: Tienes permisos para leer todos los archivos.?

Comment: Si, si los tengo

Comment: Prueba con otro directorio o otra extensión de archivos, trata de encontrar que diferencia hay entre los que no aparecen con los que si

Comment: Podrias darme una idea de como asignarle un número a cada path

Comment: Solo agregalos a una lista si no existe, cuando exista no lo agregues. edito el codigo de mi respuesta